# Llamar a un SP desde otro SP ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql

Tengo  el siguiente SP ,

```
create or replace PROCEDURE INUP_PARTY(
    o_PARTYID2010 OUT VARCHAR )
AS
  v_partyMAX NUMBER :=0;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(PARTYID2010) INTO v_partyMAX FROM PARTY2010;
  INSERT
  INTO PARTY2010
    (
      PARTYID2010
    )
    VALUES
    (
      sys_guid()
    )
  RETURNING PARTYID2010
  INTO o_PARTYID2010;
END;
```

Y tengo otro SP que podria ser el siguiente

```
create or replace PROCEDURE INUP_USER(
    v_F1DOMAINAPPLICATIONID VARCHAR2,
    v_F1PARTYID20104009 VARCHAR2, 
    v_F1USERTYPEID40284009 VARCHAR2,
    v_HINT4009 VARCHAR2,
    v_IMAGEPROFILE4009 VARCHAR2,
    v_PASSWORD4009 VARCHAR2,
    v_PASSWORDEXPIRATIONDATE4009 DATE,
    v_PASSWORDSALT4009 VARCHAR2,
    v_RECOVERYPASSWORDMODE VARCHAR2,
    v_STATUS4009 VARCHAR2,
    v_USERACCOUNT4009 VARCHAR2,
    v_USERDESCRIPTION4009 VARCHAR2,
    v_USERID    VARCHAR2 

)
AS 
v_UserCount NUMBER := 0;
vl_UserID varchar(100);

    IF(v_F1PARTYID20104009 is null)
    // aqui llamaría al SP anterior y quisiera guardarme el out del sp 
    anterior
```

La verdad investige por google pero no encontre nada que me guiara , cualquier ayuda es de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacer la llamada es muy sencillo. Lo que tal vez no sea tan obvio es, cómo asignar el resultado a `v_F1PARTYID20104009`, que parece ser tu intención.

Si ese es el caso, la respuesta es que no se puede.  A los parámetros de entrada, como lo es `v_F1PARTYID20104009`, no les puedes cambiar el valor.  De modo que lo siguiente no es legal:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INUP_USER(
    -- ...
    v_F1PARTYID20104009 VARCHAR2, 
    -- ...
)
AS 
BEGIN
    IF v_F1PARTYID20104009 is null THEN
        INUP_PARTY(v_F1PARTYID20104009); -- no se puede así.
    END IF;
END;
```

Lo que debes hacer es copiar `v_F1PARTYID20104009` a una variable local. Luego puedes emplear esta variable local para hacer la llamada al SP `INUP_PARTY`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INUP_USER(
    -- ...
    v_F1PARTYID20104009 VARCHAR2, 
    -- ...
)
AS
    w_F1PARTYID20104009 VARCHAR2(100); -- variable local
BEGIN
    w_F1PARTYID20104009 := v_F1PARTYID20104009; -- hacer copia

    IF w_F1PARTYID20104009 is null THEN
        INUP_PARTY(w_F1PARTYID20104009); -- ahora sí se puede.
    END IF;

    -- sigue usando la variable local a partir de aquí.
END;
```

Otra opción hubiera sido de cambiar `v_F1PARTYID20104009` para que sea un parámetro `IN OUT`, pero no estoy seguro que esto tendría sentido en tu caso.

---

Nota aparte: Tu SP `INUP_PARTY` lo veo bien raro. No entiendo cómo te funciona. Siendo que `sys_guid()` devuelve un `BINARY`, no veo como la asignación `SELECT MAX(PARTYID2010) INTO v_partyMAX FROM PARTY2010` puede funcionar ya que `v_partyMAX` no es del mismo tipo. De hecho ni entiendo de qué sirve esa asignación. Solo lo menciono de paso, ya que esa no es la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias  sstan , por la respuesta tan elaborada , la verdad te pasaste  muchas gracias , y si eso que mencionas tenes toda la razon , estaba concentrado mas en como resolver lo de la llamada que en arreglar ese SP pero tienes razon